# The named parameter 'body' isn't defined + The named parameter 'header' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm new to programming in general and very new to flutter, I get this following error message on both the "body" and "header" in the code which is marked in bold. I have tried everything I could find online for any help, but now found any solution, I figure this probobly isn't the hardest thing for someone who knows programming to solve, but I'm a beginner so I would really like the help. Thanks in advance.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'model.dart';

const API_URL = 'https://todoapp-api-pyq5q.ondigitalocean.app';
const API_KEY = '7037674e-2262-4502-a2e1-29c940bd2a7a';

class Api {
  static Future addTodoModel(TodoModel todo) async {
    var json = todo.toJson();
    var bodyString = jsonEncode(json);
    

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse('$API_URL/todos?key=$API_KEY',
        **body: bodyString, headers:** {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response;
    } else {
      print('error on add');
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future updateTodo(TodoModel todo, todoId) async {
    var json = todo.toJson();
    var bodyString = jsonEncode(json);

    var response = await http.put(Uri.parse('$API_URL/todos/$todoId?key=$API_KEY',
        **body: bodyString, headers:** {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response;
    } else {
      print('error on update');
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future removeTodoModel(String todoId) async {
    try {
      var response = await http.delete(Uri.parse('$API_URL/todos/$todoId?key=$API_KEY'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response;
      }
      print('exception on remove');
    } catch (exception) {
      throw exception;
    }
  }

  static Future<List<TodoModel>> getTodoModel() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('$API_URL/todos?key=$API_KEY'));
      var json = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return json.map<TodoModel>((data) {
        return TodoModel.fromJson(data);
      }).toList();
    } catch (exception) {
      throw exception;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Uri.parse]

The Uri.parse funtion has no "header" or "body" parameter.

"headers" and "body" should be post method's params, like this:
[image: http post]

Comment: Thank you. I never used Uri.parse before, how should I add them as a parameter, my newbie ways didn't work...

Comment: Please check my edited answer, maybe helpful for you :)

Comment: Thank you, that made it worked after I tried a couple of times! Now I don't get any error message before hand, but when I try to debug it, I get "Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'" on the second title in "body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{'title': title,}),. Any ideas what that can be?

Comment: The variable "title" can not be null before used in jsonEncode method.

Answer (score 0):

Body and Headers are available in method of http.
For example:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// POST method

   final response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {}, // Map<String*, String*>* headers
      body: json.encode(params), // params is Map<String, dynamic>
    );
```